# Camel JPA 'consumeDelete' when called?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, apache-camel

So I'm using camel-jpa and set the `consumeDelete` property to `true` so that the consumed entity gets removed, after it was consumed. What I'd like to know is: when will the entity be removed during the chain-process?

Is there a specific point, where the entity will be removed? Is there a specific step in the route, where it happens?

Answer (score 2):

Its removed when the message is completed being routed, eg not before routing, or during routing.

In other words it happens automatic as the last step in the route, if the message was processed successfully. If you have an error of some sorts which is not handled, then the record is not deleted, so Camel can try again. However you can use Camel error handling to handle the error so the message is regarded being processed successfully so the JPA deletes the record.

Comment: I got into the same problem but in case of an error the delegation is not going to the exception handler instead tx is marked as rollback and its keep trying to process the same row. Though the error handler is not passed in jpa instead i have added onException on route